# List remove code in python not working properly

Tags: python, list

Here is my code:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d','e']

b = a.remove('b')

print(a)

print(b)
```

It prints that `b` is `None`. I also want `b` to be `'b'`.

Comment: .remove() doesn't return anything...it removes an item from a, which is why it returns none.

Comment: That _is_ working properly. `list.remove` returns `None` - you know what it removed, it removed what you asked it to remove (and if it couldn't find it, a `ValueError` gets thrown).

Comment: `list.remove(elem_)` returns `None`. And It only changes initial list

Comment: You need to write a.remove('b') in it's own line. Then you can create b by b = a and then print a and b. However, you'll get the same result if you print then.

Comment: "I also want ``b`` to be ``'b'``." Why not use ``b = 'b'`` then?

Answer (score 1):

Python list remove() function doesn't return anything - it removes the item (if found) *in situ*

To achieve your objective:

```
['a','b','c','d','e']
b = 'b'
a.remove(b)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's `remove()` does not have a return value, so `b` is always `None`

Take a look at this snippet:

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> print(a)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> a.remove("b")
>>> print(a)
['a', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

`remove()` removes the value from list but return `None`. You might need `pop()`.

```py
a = ['a','b','c','d','e']

b = a.pop(a.index("b"))

print(a)

print(b)
```

**Output:**

```py
['a', 'c', 'd', 'e']
b
```

Answer (score -1):

Variable Vs function

b = a.remove('b')

This is a variable, a variable will do an action and store the result returned. Your variable removes b from the list a so b stores nothing as remove is an action (function) but doesn't return anything. Therefor nothing is stored. So when you call b you get nothing.

If you changed b into a function, now whenever you use b() b will be removed perminetantly from the list a. So later if you add b again to the list you can use b() function to remove it again.

This example removes then adds back b when you use function b()

Code:

```
alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e']

print(alphabet)
def b(): # this is a function 
    alphabet.remove('b') #removes 'b'
    print(alphabet) #returns result to cons
    alphabet.insert(1, 'b')#adds b back
    return 
b() #functions need to be called to work
print(alphabet)
```

Now whenever you call b() it will be your alphabet without the first letter b in it.

This is an over the top explanation but I hope this helps you understand python better.